# Develop python in vim use fisa-vim-config, short key '\r' won't work

Tags: python, vim

I'm looking for a VIM config for edit python file, then I found this docker image [fedeg/python-vim](https://store.docker.com/community/images/fedeg/python-vim) which is based on [fisadev/fisa-vim-config](https://github.com/fisadev/fisa-vim-config)
I read this line in the docs

> Run the curren python file and display the output on a split with \r.

But it doesn't work for me,
Press '\' + 'r' only delete some chars,even input Control Character carriage return (Ctrl+M) won't help me.
You see there is an open issue for it,but no one answered it.
I searched all vim config file in directory .vim,only find 
one plugin called jedi-vim use this short key.
Is the document out of date,or I have some misunderstand about it.

On macOS 10.12.5
Terminal: iterm2 Build 3.2.1
docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:13:02 2018
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:22:38 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
Image:fedeg/python-vim Tag:3
```